# Sudden decrease in pages crawled per day

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, web-crawlers, crawl-rate

During the last few days, Googlebot has crawled much less page in my site than it normally does. I'm not seeing any new errors, and haven't identified a reason for this. Is such a hugh and sudden decrease a sign there is a problem? Can this be just a temporary thing?

[image]

**Update:** The `Time spent downloading a page (in milliseconds)` graph remained steady.

Comment: Have you checked the Page speed?

Comment: @SathiyaKumar yes, that graph is steady.

Comment: Then it might be a common issue as Geoff Jackson said.

Comment: How is your analytics, any drop in traffic?

Comment: @moobot No drop so far

Answer (score 2):

Pages that are not frequently updated or are not important in the eyes of a search engine, after time, will be crawled (visited) by search engines less and could eventually be dropped from Google's index altogether eventually.

This doesn't mean there is an issue at all and is quite common for large sites with many pages.

Comment: I accept your point @GeoffJackson